# Angular custom mat input with ControlValueAccessor do not update outer value in reactive from

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with my custom mat-file-input field. I set initial value:

```
this.editFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    logo: [null]
});
```

From server I receive main object that have logo url string value:

```
this.editFormGroup.patchValue(response);
```

And I do not want to do modifications in my Page Controller. Instead, I want set string and then inside my custom Control that implements `ControlValueAccessor` I want automatically fetch this image from server and set value as `File` object

```
@Input()
    get value(): File | null {
        return this.fileControl.value;
    }
    set value(value: File | string | null) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            this.writeValue(null);
            this.fetchFromServer(value);
        } else {
            this.fileControl.setValue(value);
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.onChange(value);
            this.stateChanges.next();
        }
    }
```

But `this.editFormGroup.value.logo` is not changing. Is there any way to change reactive form value inside custom control ?

Comment: What does `fetchValueFromServer` look like?  Does it call `writeValue` after it fetches?

Comment: @BizzyBob yes, it is calling API and then use `writeValue(object)` to set value as File object. The main idea for this that you do not need  to think about this modifications in controller every time

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use patchValue instead of setValue. Setvalue is for the whole form (all controls) and with patchValue its just for one form control.